# UIView Animation with a LiveFrost LFGlassView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm implementing the LiveFrost LFGlassView and trying to add animate the view, but the LFGLassView doesn't seem to be able to dynamically frost whatever it covers as the animation occurs.

```
LFGlassView *view = [[LFGlassView alloc] initwithframe:CGMakeRect(0,0,320,300)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^(void) {
      [view setCenter:CGPointMake(0,400)];
}];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're using a 3rd party class and it's not behaving as you expect it to, you should probably submit a bug report with its developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used it, but have seen others do in the past. From what I read before, you would need to add it as a subview of the view you wish to blur.

Ex:

Blurring `self.view`

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

First google hit I got the following.

Similar issue is asked before on the developer's site and his response was:

> The idea is that the developer should be able to blur any target layer
>   of their choosing that is part of any view hierarchy in the app. The
>   Core Animation API makes this part a bit tricky to pull off and make
>   it work across a wide range of use cases, but I'll find some way to
>   make it work.

Another similar [request](https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost/issues/9) regarding animating the blur radius:

Quoting:

> It's not quite as high on the list of priorities right now, but that
>   would probably be our next major release, 2.0 or something like that.
>
> As for blurradius, we do enough pre-caching that making blurradius
>   animatable will probably be really, really slow. But I think it's
>   still worth trying.

It was 3 months ago. Might not solve your issue here, but at least providing you with some information regarding animation issues / features about this. Can't be more of help, as I never used it.

Comment: that's all I needed. Thanks so much